# OpenOffice Calc: Fill Dropdown from Database?

Tags: postgresql, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

Is it possible to fill a dropdown list for a cell in OpenOffice Calc with entries from a database using a query?

I've found how to create the dropdown list using Data -> Validity and I created an .odb file to connect to by postgresql database using File -> New -> Database, but I can't find any input on what to do from that point on.

What I want is for example that when the Calc file is opened, the dropdown for the cell is populated by executing a select query against the database I created the .odb file for.